# Determining a function from a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

The question at hand is this:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence satisfying $a_0 = \frac{1}{5}$, $a_1 = \frac{4}{25}$ and for $n \geq 2$,  $a_n = \frac{4}{5}a_{n-1} - \frac{1}{5}a_{n-2} $.

a)Consider the power series $f(z) = \sum_{n} a_n z^n $ of radius of convergence R. Determine $f$ explicitly.

b)Use (a) to find the explicit expression of $a_n$  and the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n} a_n z^n$.

I dont even know how to start with this one. Any help would be great...

Answer (score 0):

For all $n$,
$$a_{n+2}z^{n+2}=\frac{4}{5} za_{n+1}z^{n+1} -\frac{1}{5}z^2a_{n}z^{n}.$$
Provided $R>0$, we can sum and then have for all $|z|<R$ that
$$f(z)-a_1z-a_0=\frac{4}{5}z(f(z)-a_0)-\frac{1}{5}z^2f(z).$$
Plug in initial values, re-arrange to get $f(z)$ as a quotient of a linear polynomial by $(z-2+\text{i})(z-2-\text{i})$; now put it into partial fractions to get $f(z)$ as a sum $$\frac{A}{1-\frac{z}{2+\text{i}} }+\frac{B}{1-\frac{z}{2-\text{i}}}$$  where we know $A,B$; so by the Binomial Theorem
$$f(z)=\sum \left(A(\frac{1}{2+\text{i}})^k + B(\frac{1}{2-\text{i}})^k  \right)z^k,$$ whose radius is $$|2+\text{i}|=|2-\text{i}|=\sqrt{5}.$$

To make this a proof you need to prove $R>0$ in a non-circular way. It is easy to prove by induction that all $|a_n|\leqslant 1$, so $R\geqslant 1$.

Comment: I see, thank you good sir

Comment: i am getting a different fraction that cannot be separated by partial fractions. Can you please elaborate on the binomial theorem part

Comment: Apologies. Carelessness. Let me re-do it.

Comment: i'm really sorry to ask again, but I dont think I understand how to get the sequence in part b

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n z^n = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{z}{25} + \sum_{n = 2} a_n z^n = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{z}{25} + \frac{4z}{5} \sum_{n = 1} a_n z^n - \frac{z^2}{5} \sum_{n = 0} a_n z^n.$$
This yields
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{z}{25} + \frac{4z}{5} (f(z) - \frac{1}{5}) - \frac{z^2}{5} f(z).$$
Solving this for $f$ yields (if the nominator is non-zero)
$$f(z) = \frac{\frac{1}{5} - \frac{19z}{25}}{1 - \frac{4z}{5} + \frac{z^2}{5}} = \frac{5 - 19z}{25 - 20z + 5z^2}.$$
(I hope i didn't make a mistake)